# query select on while loop php pdo sql server odbc

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a query like this:

```
$quDetail = $DB_con1->prepare("SELECT * FROM TTK_D WHERE NO_TTK=:no_ttk");

$quDetail->execute(array(":no_ttk" => $no_ttk));

$arrDetail = array();

while($dtDetail = $quDetail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    // query problem
    $queryLanjut = "SELECT * 
                    FROM PPN_IN pi 
                      INNER JOIN TTK_D td ON pi.NO_REG=td.NO_REG 
                    WHERE td.NO_TTK='".$dtDetail->NO_REG."'";
    $stmtLanjut = $DB_con1->prepare($queryLanjut);
    $stmtLanjut->execute();
    $dtLanjut = $stmtLanjut->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

In MySQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL no problem with this techhnique, but on SQL SERVER 2008 R2, query just execute 1 record.. (not looping)

anybody else can help me with this problem? if this technique cannot implementation on SQL SERVER, can you guys give me a solution??

I really appreciate your help,
thank you.

Comment: Have you check the return value of execute()? It returns true if the query succeeded. If it returns false, check if there are any errors. (function errorInfo())

Comment: Are you sure that there is more than one row to find?

Comment: and are you sure that the first `execute` returns true?